# keeping data in 'this' VS 'state'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I wonder is it okay to keep some UI state as instance variables(`this`) rather than in react state object. For example making controlled inputs sometimes becomes tedious, wouldn't it be better to keep it like:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class extends React.Component {
    selectedCheckboxes = new Set();
    searchInput = '';
    radioButton = undefined;

    onCheckboxChange = ({target: {value}}) => {
        if (this.selectedCheckboxes.has(value)) {
            this.selectedCheckboxes.delete(value);
        } else {
            this.selectedCheckboxes.add(value);
        }
    };

    submit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const searchInput = this.searchInput;
        const checkboxes = [...this.selectedCheckboxes];
        const radioButton = this.radioButton;

        console.log(searchInput, checkboxes, radioButton);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form className="Example" onSubmit={this.submit}>
                <div className="checkboxes">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="a" onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}/>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="b" onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}/>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="c" onChange={this.onCheckboxChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className="search">
                    <input type="text" onChange={e => this.searchInput = e.target.value}/>
                </div>
                <div className="radio-buttons">
                    <input type="radio"
                           name="radio"
                           value="1"
                           onChange={e => this.radioButton = e.target.value}/>
                    <input type="radio"
                           name="radio"
                           value="2"
                           onChange={e => this.radioButton = e.target.value}/>
                    <input type="radio"
                           name="radio"
                           value="3"
                           onChange={e => this.radioButton = e.target.value}/>
                </div>
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

I know downside of this approach is that component is not notified when value of `this`-variables has changed so component will not update. But on the other side sometimes it is not neccessary (like in my example) and it can boost performance as it dont triger re-render, and avoids reconcilation.

[Reference](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00)

Comment: If you don't want it to re-render then sure.

Comment: *"But on the other side sometimes it is not neccessary  ..."* then it's perfectly fine.

Comment: If it works for you - do it.

Comment: Thanks. My concern was that maybe there can be problems with keeping data synchronous.

Comment: you should put this `selectedCheckboxes = new Set()` into the constructor or this Set is shared throughout all instances of this component.

Comment: @Thomas is it? I believe that only static variables are shared across all instances. I've seen examples of people declaring react state this way... I could be wrong.

Comment: No, static variables are defined on the class, they ain't shared at all. But your code is sugar for `yourComponent.prototype.selectedCheckboxes = new Set();` so all instances reference the same Set. If you don't want that you have to lazily create the object on the particular instance; for example in the constructor, or in some method, ... pretty much anywhere in the class but the class definition.

Comment: @Thomas I've created `class Shoe { size = 20 }` then created 3 instances of this class `cons s1 = new Shoe() ...` then I change first one `s1.size = 40` then I logged size for every shoe and only one had size of 40.   https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Comment: I was talking about Objects and references, not primitives. But as it turns out, babel takes care of this and actually puts this declaration into the constructor; nice. Just be careful if you ever remove babel from this equation.